# Quantifying and hedging for FX risk

Tags: investing, foreign-exchange, risk-management

So I am new to investing and currently use an AUD account to invest, but mostly trade USD denoted instruments (mainly XAUUSD). Therefore I am getting unwanted exposure to AUDUSD because of the conversion into my account currency.

So my question is, what different methods would you suggest to hedge against this risk? From what I have read on the main methods are using swap, options or futures. Obviously, I could also take a position on AUDUSD, but in this case how would I quantify the risk to determine the amount I need to hold in AUDUSD to hedge?

Thank you in advance! Any help is honestly very appreciated.

Comment: To confirm - I assume you live in Aus and have no particular need for USD? Any future desire to move there, or frequently vacation there?

Comment: You are correct and yes no particular need for USD. I also do not see myself moving there, at least not in the near future.

Comment: Buying the AUD/USD, in an AUD account of home currency, is the same thing as selling the USD. Then a retail Forex account would be the easiest method since it relates to spot prices. Or the investor might prefer futures contracts for reasons of more simple accounting or otherwise.

Comment: Right that is what I was also thinking. But how would you determine the amount of AUDUSD to hold?

Comment: For every dollar bought in the first account then a dollar should be sold in the hedge account. In a leveraged account go by position size and not margin deposit. But AUD/USD relates to the position size in AUD. Just calculate the position size in USD. Or with a USD futures contract in an AUD account just look-up the size of the contract

Comment: In the following software, 10000 of funds in the first currency, at a price in the first currency of 0.728, and at a margin deposit of 3%, produces a maximum recommended position size of 250000 in the first currency. Or 7280 of funds in the second currency, at a price in the first currency of 0.728, and a margin deposit of 3%, produces a maximum recommended position size of 250000 in the first currency: http://www.kbhscape.com/forexing.htm . But what the poster wants is funds in the first currency and position size in the second currency. That's 250000 * 0.728 or 182000 size in 2nd currency.